# How to fix the size of v-content

Tags: html, css, vuejs2, vuex

I have 2 html components that I need to be a fixed size. 1 is a `v-list` the other is a visual editor. If the `v-list` gets too big a scroll bar appears on the page. To solve this I need to set the `v-list` `max-height: 100%` but this doesn't work because the `v-content` grows to fit the content inside of it. How do I set `v-content` max height to be the initial page height (with proper padding) and not grow or shrink when content is inside it?

[v-content with padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtnwK.png)

[v-content bad overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdRgs.png)

```
       <v-content class="main-content">
            <router-view/>
        </v-content>
```

```
<v-container pa-0 fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout column>
            <v-toolbar height="40px" color="white" flat>
                <v-btn to="/gitremote" depressed color="#00b259" class="white--text" small>Open</v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>

            <v-toolbar height="33px" color="white" flat>
                <v-breadcrumbs :items="breadcrumbs" divider="/"></v-breadcrumbs>
            </v-toolbar>

            <v-layout row>
                <v-flex xs2>
                    <v-card color="white" height="100%">
                        <v-list two-line>
                            <v-list-tile v-for="listitem in currentDirectoryItems" :key="listitem" avatar
                                         @click="navigateTo(listitem.itemType, listitem.itemId, listitem.name)">
                                <v-list-tile-avatar>
                                    <v-icon>{{listitem.icon}}</v-icon>
                                </v-list-tile-avatar>
                                <v-list-tile-content>
                                    <v-list-tile-title>{{listitem}}</v-list-tile-title>
                                    <v-list-tile-sub-title>{{listitem.subtitle}}</v-list-tile-sub-title>
                                </v-list-tile-content>
                                <v-list-tile-action>
                                    <!-- <CommandMenu
                                      v-bind:listItem="listitem"
                                      v-bind:commandsObject="gitRepoItemCommands"
                                      /> -->
                                </v-list-tile-action>
                            </v-list-tile>
                        </v-list>
                    </v-card>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex>
                    <v-card>
                        EDITOR!!!!1
                    </v-card>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

Comment: What happens if you add the property `max-height: 100vh` to your ".main-content" class

Comment: It didn't work, I added `overflow-y: auto` and that seems to be the right direction but I have some clipping issues with the `v-footer`. `v-content` isn't adding the right amount of padding for the `v-footer`